# Pyramid with multiple elements at each level in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, visualization

I have to create a Pyramid visualization from data using d3.js. A sample view is attached. There are 2 challenges for which I am looking for help.

1. I understand how to create a Pyramid looking at the example given below, but I dont understand how can I add multiple elements (Shown in the image with value like A, B, C etc) at each level
   http://bl.ocks.org/ronakrrb/73e9204a66e2a9c1fee8
2. I want to append a tree like structure for some of the elements in the lowest level.

Any help is appreciated.
I cannot use a tree instead of Pyramid as there is no parent-child relationship between the elements of each layer

[image]

Example Demo Data:

```js
const data = [
    { Name: "G", level: 1},
    { Name: "F", level: 2},
    { Name: "DE", level: 2},
    { Name: "C", level: 3},
    { Name: "B", level: 3},
    { Name: "A", level: 3, team: [1,2,3]}
]
```

Comment: Can you add your data please? Like values for A - G in the data structure you would be using, with any of the 1-3 tree nodes also included? Then we can give a real working demo.

Comment: @AlexL the values A-G are sample values...Basically I am trying to create an employment hierarchy and the A - G are the role names or designations in the organization. Hope that helps you to help me. Thanks

Comment: Ok, but the point is, I don't want to give you a solution and then you say "sorry my data doesn't look like this" or for me to make assumptions and then you say "no that's not what I mean". Check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. If possible, structure your question as a minimal reproducible example. I have edited your question now, can I use that sample data? (Remember, D3 is "Data Driven Documents". Data comes first usually  )

Comment: @AlexL I didn't spend much time to understand your comment. My bad and apologies for that. Your data structure works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it - This is the first **very** rough pass. If you say it's along the right direction, I can improve and refine it:

(I would need to refine how the spacing occurs, I would need to also add on the team members to letter A and would need to generally clean it up etc.)

**UPDATE 11-Jun-20** - cleaned up spacing and added boxes around the letters and circles around the numbers.

```js
var width = 700,
      height = 450,
      radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

  var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .range(["#255aee","#3a6fff","#4f84ff","rgb(101,154,302)","rgb(122,175,323)", "rgb(144,197,345)", "rgb(165,218,366)"]);

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .append("g")
  //*    
  const data = [
    { Name: "G", level: 1},
    { Name: "F", level: 2},
    { Name: "DE", level: 2},
    { Name: "C", level: 3},
    { Name: "B", level: 3},
    { Name: "A", level: 3, team: [1,2,3]}
  ];
  //*/
  const grouped = Object.values(data.reduce((aggObj, item) => {
    
    if (!aggObj[item.level]){
      aggObj[item.level] = {level: item.level, names: []};
    }
    aggObj[item.level].names.push({name: item.Name, team: item.team});
    return aggObj;
  }, {}));
  
  //console.log(grouped);
  
      var pyramid = d3.pyramid()
          .size([width,height])
          .value(function(d) { return d.level; });

      var line = d3.svg.line()
          .interpolate('linear-closed')
          .x(function(d,i) { return d.x; })
          .y(function(d,i) { return d.y; });

      var g = svg.selectAll(".pyramid-group")
          .data(pyramid(grouped)) //swap for grouped data
          .enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "pyramid-group");

      g.append("path")
          .attr("d", function (d){ return line(d.coordinates); })
          .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.level); });

      var textBoxes = g.selectAll(".textBoxes")
          .data((d) => {
            const helperObj = {};
            helperObj.coordinates = d.coordinates;
            helperObj.level = d.level;
            const len = d.names.length;
            helperObj.len = d.names.length;
            if(d.coordinates.length === 4) {
                const left = d.coordinates[0].x;
                const right = d.coordinates[3].x;
                const topLeft = d.coordinates[1].x;
                const topRight = d.coordinates[2].x;
                const start = left + ((topLeft - left) / 2);
                const end = right - ((right - topRight) / 2);
                const sep = (end - start) / len;
                helperObj.start = start;
                helperObj.end = end;
                helperObj.sep = sep;
                const yCenter = (((d.coordinates[0].y-d.coordinates[1].y)/2)+d.coordinates[1].y) + 5;
                helperObj.yCenter = yCenter;
                helperObj.yDiff = (d.coordinates[0].y-d.coordinates[1].y);
            } else {
                const left = d.coordinates[1].x;
                const right = d.coordinates[2].x;
                const start = left + ((right - left) / 4);
                const end = right - ((right - left) / 4);
                const sep = (end - start) / len;
                helperObj.start = start;
                helperObj.end = end;
                helperObj.sep = sep;
                helperObj.yCenter = (d.coordinates[0].y + d.coordinates[1].y)/2 + 10;
                helperObj.yDiff = (d.coordinates[1].y-d.coordinates[0].y) * 0.9;
            } 
                  
            return d.names.map((e,i) => {
              const name = e.name;
              const team = e.team || [];
              const teamLen = team.length;
              return {...helperObj, i, name, team, teamLen};
            })
          })
          .enter().append("g");
          
      textBoxes.append("rect")
          .attr({
              "y": function (d,i) {
                  //console.log(d)
                  return d.yCenter - (d.yDiff/8);
              },
              "x": function (d,i) {
                  return d.start + ((i+0.05) * d.sep);
              },
              "width": function (d,i) {
                  return d.sep * 0.9;         
              },
              "height": function (d,i) {
                  return (d.yDiff/8) * 3;         
              },
              "fill": function (d,i) {
                  return "#e0f4ff";         
              },
              "rx": function (d,i) {
                  return d.sep * 0.1;   
              }
          });
          
      textBoxes.append("text")
          .attr({
              "y": function (d,i) {
                  //console.log(d)
                  return d.yCenter;
              },
              "x": function (d,i) {
                  return d.start + ((i+0.5) * d.sep);
              }
          })          
          .style("text-anchor", "middle")
          .style("alignment-baseline", "hanging")
          .style("font-size", "x-large")
          .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
          
      var teamMembers = textBoxes.selectAll(".teamMembers")
          .data((d) => {
            const itemCopy = {...d};
            const teamCopy = [...d.team];
            delete itemCopy.team;
            return d.team.map(e => ({...itemCopy, teamMember: e}));
          });
      teamMembers.enter().append("line")
          .attr({
              "y1": function (d,i) {
                  //console.log(d)
                  return d.yCenter + (d.yDiff/3);
              },
              "x1": function (d,i) {
                  return d.start + ((d.i+0.15) * d.sep) + ((i+0.5) * ((0.7*d.sep)/d.teamLen));
              },
              "y2": function (d,i) {
                  //console.log(d)
                  return d.yCenter + (d.yDiff/6);
              },
              "x2": function (d,i) {
                  return d.start + ((d.i+0.15) * d.sep) + (0.5 * (0.7*d.sep));
              },
              "stroke": function (d,i) {
                  //console.log(d)
                  return "black";
              },
              "stroke-width": function (d,i) {
                  return "2";
              }
          });    
      teamMembers.enter().append("circle")
          .attr({
              "cy": function (d,i) {
                  //console.log(d)
                  return d.yCenter + (d.yDiff/3);
              },
              "cx": function (d,i) {
                  return d.start + ((d.i+0.15) * d.sep) + ((i+0.5) * ((0.7*d.sep)/d.teamLen));
              },
              "r": function (d,i) {
                  return d.sep * 0.05;
              }
          });
      teamMembers.enter().append("text")
          .attr({
              "y": function (d,i) {
                  //console.log(d)
                  return d.yCenter + (d.yDiff/3);
              },
              "x": function (d,i) {
                  return d.start + ((d.i+0.15) * d.sep) + ((i+0.5) * ((0.7*d.sep)/d.teamLen));
              },
              "fill": function (d,i) {
                  return "white";
              }
          })
          .style("text-anchor", "middle")
          .style("alignment-baseline", "middle")
          .style("font-size", "large")
          .text(function(d) { return d.teamMember; });

      d3.select("body").append("table")
          .attr({
              "id" : "footer",
              "width": width + "px"
          })

      d3.select("body #footer").append("tr")
          .attr({
              "class" : "PykCharts-credits",
              "id" : "credit-datasource"
          })
          .append("td")
          .style("text-align","left")
          .html("<span style='pointer-events:none;'>Credits: </span><a href='http://pykcharts.com' target='_blank'>"+  "Pykcharts" +"</a>");
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                font: 10px sans-serif;
                }

            .arc path {
                stroke: #fff;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/charts.pykih.com/gists/pyramid.js"></script>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This is good start @AlexL. I would be happy to each of the elements in the levels i.e A, B, C in the form of a box or something...I mean some visual separation between the elements. Thanks a ton for your efforts.

Comment: @sid let me know what you think of the updated cleaned up answer.

Comment: I tried your code and it works well. The tree structure coming out of A, can it be d3 tree structure. Also, can the roles be clickable. The purpose of the whole structure is to allow the team to navigate the roles and the hierarchy. I had this idea and trying to figure out way to do it. I know I might be asking for too much. I am thankful for your help so far. I have accepted your answer.

Comment: Glad it worked and was helpful. When you say d3 tree struct you mean like this? - https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8375092 - also, when you say can the roles be clickable, what do you want to happen when you click? Do you mean, click “A” and the tree below it is shown, click “A” again and the tree is hidden? Or something else? Does sound like a decent amount of work to add those features.

Comment: Yes, to both of your questions. There are quite some features I want to add. So the scope is now beyond a questions. Its more of building the solution. You have given me a good direction. I will take it up from these. Thanks a ton for your efforts.

Comment: I got the idea of joining shapes from this work - https://bl.ocks.org/bumbeishvili/ccaad3234864a1cc36b17c4538882b2c

Comment: You’re very welcome, glad I could help. That tree / bar chart is really cool! Good luck with building out the solution, if you get stuck, feel free to post another question, I often check the d3.js tag, so I might even see it if you do :)